# is it possible to have multiple applications, each with a different subdomain deployed in a single Azure Website

Tags: azure

I've seen that you can host multiple applications in a single azure website, my question is, **will I be able to assign a different subdomain for each application running in the same website**? e.g: app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you select the web hosting plan mode "Basic" or "Standart" you deploy as many websites as you want without any additional costs so why mutiple application on one website instead of one website per app? see pricing: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

Comment: Thanks for this peice of information, I had no idea you could do this. So if I create a new website how do I assign it to the same hosting plan?

Comment: If you create a website there is a dropdown where you can select your plan (e.g. Default1).